# UpdateAysnc throws "Field 'id' is not recognied" error

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I have the following code, written in C# using a .NET Core 2.0 console app. I've used these same variables for an adding function and all works fine.

The `GetAsync` works and pulls back the list item. When the `UpdateAsync` is called I get an error return from Microsoft Graph:

```
Messsage: Field 'id' is not recognied
HResult: -2146233088
request-id: 0682cf9f-c828-43f1-bc9e-acb21631a58e
date: 01/11/2017 7:28:38 Ticks 636450912000000000
```

*note that "recognied" is the actual spelling returned*

This is the code I'm using:

```cs
var listItemId = SharePointIdToInSiteMapping.GetValueOrDefault(siteRecord.InSiteID);
var graphClient = GetGraphClient();

var listItem = await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items[listItemId].Request()
    .Expand(i = > i.Fields)
    .GetAsync();

listItem.Fields.AdditionalData["Title"] = siteRecord.Title;

try
{
    var request = graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items[listItemId].Request();
    var result = await request.UpdateAsync(listItem);
    Console.WriteLine($"Updated List Item at {result.WebUrl}");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error updating {siteRecord.Title}");
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

**UPDATED CODE THAT WORKS FOR THOSE THAT ARE INTERESTED**

```
var result = await graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items[listItemId].Request().UpdateAsync(
  new ListItem(){
    Fields = new FieldValueSet{
      AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>{
        {"Title", "A change title"}
      }
     }
   }
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this error is that you're passing the entire `ListItem` object to `UpdateAsync`. Since the `id` property is read-only, it is returning an error.

In order to send an update to the `ListItem` you should pass in a new `ListItem` object with only the properties you wish to change:

```
var result = await graphClient
    .Sites["siteId"]
    .Lists["listId"]
    .Items["listItemId"]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(new ListItem()
    {
        // Properties you wish to change
    });
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. When I see new ListItem I think I automatically assume it will create a new ListItem.

Comment: Super common mistake. It's one of the challenges when attempting to design an object oriented wrapper to a stateless REST API. The objects don't always behave the way you expect them too.